# What does "which" refer to

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

[Source](https://dokumen.pub/economists-at-war-how-a-handful-of-economists-helped-win-and-lose-the-world-wars-0198846002-9780198846000.html)

> Von Neumann had been working in academia for the US military on problems of computing and defence. In the post-war years Kantorovich was in a similar position in the USSR. Kantorovich and von Neumann had met in Moscow in 1935, little realizing that they would be pitting their prodigious mathematical talents against each other’s country a decade later, **a more personalized form of game theory than either might have ever envisaged**.

---

What does the boldfaced part refer to?

Comment: It refers to whatever it is that is a more personalized form of game theory, namely, Kantorovich and von Neumann pitting their prodigious mathematical talents against each other’s country. _Which - pronoun · determiner - used referring to something previously mentioned when introducing a clause giving further information._ (Oxford Languages).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It seems to me that it would have been better to ask what "*a more personalized form of game theory*" refers to.

Comment: Do you mean 'it would have been better to ask what "a more personalized form of game theory" **means**'? If your answer is 'yes', then that is what you should have asked, and you should ask another question, and **not** edit this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the preceding clause: "that they would be pitting their prodigious mathematical talents against each other’s country a decade later".

Note that the relative pronoun "which" has the subject complement "a more personalized form of game theory . . .". Therefore, they should refer to the same thing. In the original sentence, "a more personalized form of game theory . . ." is in apposition to the preceding clause: "that they would be pitting their prodigious mathematical talents against each other’s country a decade later".

Converting a sentence from what you suggest (". . ., which was a more personalized form . . .") to the original text (". . ., a more personalized form . . .") involves deleting the words "which was". This is often called "whiz-deletion"; ELL's sister site ELU has [a tag covering that topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whiz-deletion), in case you're interested in reading more about it.